# Edit format of Paginate_Links()

Tags: php, pagination, paginate-links

I'm using [paginate_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) to paginate the results of a loop.

I want to style the pagination using dots instead of numbers, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

I could try to play around with the css but I would prefer a clean method.

```
example.

<-                 o o o                ->

currently.

<-                 1 2 3                ->
```

This is currently how I am outputting my links.

```
<?php

$big = 999999999;

$paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text'    => __('<div class="prev pull-left"><i class="icon-arrow_thin_left"></i></div>'),
    'next_text'    => __('<div class="next pull-right"><i class="icon-arrow_thin_right"></i></div>'),
    'type' => 'array',
    'n_display' => 'test'
) );

foreach ( $paginate_links as $pgl ) {
    echo "$pgl";
}

?>
```

Looking at the [core paginate_links() function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php/#L1996)  in Wordpress is there anyway I can modify the output of $n_display before or after.

Comment: I'd say CSS is the better way to go. You are, I think, intending to alter the display of pagination, not its meaning so CSS is a the right answer. Plus, dots will mean nothing to visitors on a screen reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clean way to do this (that I notice from quick look at rather messy code of it), but `$n_display` is passed though formatting [`number_format_i18n()`](http://queryposts.com/function/number_format_i18n/) function which does have a filter.

So you could try something like:

```
function make_number_into_dot( $number ) {
    return 'o';
}

add_filter( 'number_format_i18n', 'make_number_into_dot' );

// your pagination handling here

remove_filter( 'number_format_i18n', 'make_number_into_dot' );
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still learning and your queryposts website should help me out a lot.