# How do I make pagination_links show as 01 02 03, instead of 1 2 3?

Tags: pagination

Based on: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links how to make these links show as 01, 02, 03... rather than the normal single digit?

thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the pagination type to array. That way you can use  each link in a loop and add what you need to them:

Using the example from the codex:

```
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type' => array
) );

foreach ( $paginate_links as $link ) {
        echo sprintf("%02s", $link);
    }
```

The php sprintf function will add a leading zero.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The approved answer did not work for me. Taking a suggestion from [Edit format of Paginate_Links()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/132000/40585), I used the following code:

**PLACE IN FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
function give_numbers_leading_zero( $number ) {
    return sprintf("%02s", $number);
}
```

**PAGINATION CODE**

```
add_filter( 'number_format_i18n', 'give_numbers_leading_zero' );

$paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
    'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
    'type'         => 'array'
) );

remove_filter( 'number_format_i18n', 'give_numbers_leading_zero' );

if($paginate_links){ 
    foreach ( $paginate_links as $link ) {
        echo $link;
    }
}
```